# Issue with tool chain created using YOCTO fido branch

Tags: c, compilation, toolchain, yocto

...
13. repo init -u https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform **-b fido**

14. repo sync

## **checkout these specific commits**

15. cd /arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/sources/meta-fsl-arm/
16. git checkout master
17. git fetch
18. git checkout 663a838d38dd9124805771637232df0af01efd7c
19. cd /arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra/
20. git checkout master
21. git fetch ch
22. git fetch
23. git checkout 12cc66a9b8c3788309cf0a72c001f27abc299271
24. cd /arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/sources/poky/
25. git checkout master
26. git fetch
27. git checkout 5a51fb28dbdfcae8ceb503a5290532dd38aeb09f
28. source setup-environment wandboard

## **changed MACHINE='wandboard'**

29. *vi conf/local.conf*

## **Started building toolchain**

30. *bitbake meta-toolchain*

## **Running script i.e. generated after build step #30**

31. source  tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.8+snapshot.sh
32. ./tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-glibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.8+snapshot.sh
33. source environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

## **Cross compiling with created tool chain with absolute path**

@debian:~$ */opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c*
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

## **cross compiling with created tool chain with environment set**

@debian:~$ *arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c*
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

## **Cross compiling with created tool chain with environment set and explicitly providing include path**

@debian:~$ a*rm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I /opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/   hello.c*
In file included from /opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/features.h:389:0,
                 from /opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from hello.c:1:
/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

**Cross compilation with -v option**
@debian:~$ arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v hello.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/work-shared/gcc-5.2.0-r0/gcc-5.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-pokysdk-linux --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr --bindir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --sbindir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --libexecdir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --datadir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/com --localstatedir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/var --libdir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --includedir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include --infodir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- --without-local-prefix --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --with-cloog=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --without-isl **--with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/5.2.0** --with-build-time-tools=/arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/bin **--with-sysroot=/not/exist** --with-build-sysroot=/arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabresd --enable-poison-system-directories --with-mpfr=/arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --with-mpc=/arm/fsl-community-bsp-fido/build-sabre/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux --enable-nls --with-arch=armv7-a
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/cc1 -quiet -v hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -march=armv7-a -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase hello -version -o /tmp/ccqXSLVK.s
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.2.0 (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.2.0, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/not/exist/usr/lib/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/not/exist/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/../../../../../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/not/exist/usr/include"

## include "..." search starts here:

## include <...> search starts here:

/opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/include
 /opt/poky/1.8+snapshot/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.2.0 (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.2.0, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 4d79907806e372d157adce3e5c786751
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

I need some some help here to compile a simple hello world using tool-chain created here. Or am I missing something.

Even I am not sure why these flags sets like this:

--with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/5.2.0

--with-sysroot=/not/exist

Answer (score 2):

After so many options tried finally through with  compilation

@debian:~$ echo $CC

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --
sysroot=/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

@debian:~$ ${CC} hello.c -o out

@debian:~$ echo $?
0

Answer (score 0):

After running the "env" script file generateed from SDK,by default exports the variable flags like CC, CXX, LDFLAGS etc.,
You need to use those variables in your make files or manually.

run sdk env

```
@debian:~$  . envoiment file  
@debian:~$ echo $CC
        arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7ve -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/siva/imx7-images/sdk/meta-toolchain_sdk/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi   

@debian:~$ ${CC} hello.c -o hello
```

if you use c++ files you need to use `CXX`

```
 @debian:~$ ${CXX} hello.cpp -o hello
```

it will run successfully. so for every thing you have to use macros only.

Comment: yes its working, but why we need to use macros only. if I use Linaro toolchain , I can compile directly using arm-linaro-gcc. why not for yocto.